# I'm not able to get NSArray as return value from a function

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I'm try to get a point based structure from a function called:

```
-(NSArray *) calcRose : (float) theta
{
    //first calculate x and y 
    //we need to get width and height of uiscreen

    //myPoint[0] = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width;

    NSMutableArray *Points = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] arrayWithCapacity:2];

    float angle = [self radians:theta];
    float side = cos(n * angle);
    int cWidth = 320;
    int cHeight = 240;
    float width = cWidth * side * sin(angle) / 2 + cWidth /2;
    float height = cHeight * side * cos(angle) / 2 + cHeight /2;

    [Points addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:cWidth]];
    [Points addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:cHeight]];
    NSArray *myarr = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:Points ]autorelease ];

    return myarr;
}
```

I use below code for retrieving data from the function:

```
NSArray *tt = [[ NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self calcRose:3]     ];
```

But every time I compile the program it gives me some error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the compilation error you've seen ?

Comment: 2011-11-07 11:25:18.061 myFirstGraphicProgram[40922:40b] 0.174533
2011-11-07 11:25:18.062 myFirstGraphicProgram[40922:40b] -[__NSPlaceholderArray arrayWithCapacity:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e02a90
2011-11-07 11:25:18.063 myFirstGraphicProgram[40922:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSPlaceholderArray arrayWithCapacity:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e02a90'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 .
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: You know that you aren't using width and height, aren't you? Doesn't solve you problem though.

Comment: It's never really worthwhile to use arrayWithCapacity unless the array is going to grow fairly large -- at least 10s of entries if not 100s or 1000s.  The default size is likely in the neighborhood of 10-20, if you don't specify a size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[NSMutableArray alloc ] arrayWithCapacity:2]` definitely is wrong. Try `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2]` instead. Also, you can just use `[[self calcRose:3] retain]` rather than  `[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self calcRose:3]]`, and you only need the `retain` call if you intend to keep the array around for longer than the current runloop pass.

Comment: " -[__NSPlaceholderArray arrayWithCapacity:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e02a90 " @austinpowers MrMage got it right. arrayWithCapacity unrecognized selector sent to instance and its a runtime error not compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've simplified your sample for the purposes of the question but you seem to be doing a lot of unnecessary work. The code in your question could be rewritten as:

```
-(NSArray *) calcRose : (float) theta 
{   
    int cWidth = 320;     
    int cHeight = 240;     

    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:cWidth],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:cHeight],nil];        
}
```

`initWithCapacity` and using a mutable array is not really giving you anything besides a headache. If you want to use a mutable array, just create with `[NSMutableArray array]`, but it doesn't look like you are adding that many objects so the method I have suggested would be better.

This method returns an autoreleased array, so your calling statement can just be

```
NSArray *tt = [self calcRose:3];
```

Comment: And of course if you need a mutable array, you can still use `[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:...]`.